# Entity Framework, Automatic apply Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework Code First approach with `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true`:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DbContext, MigrateDBConfiguration>());
//////////////////////////////////

public class MigrateDBConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration<DbContext>
{
    public MigrateDBConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
}
```

The first run of the project creates the database and tables as expected. After changing my model by adding or dropping fields, I ran `Add-Migration`.  The  Migration class was generated but after running the project this exception occurs:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The model backing the 'DBContext' context has
>   changed since the database was created.

**EDIT:** Per the guidance in the answer of [arturo menchaca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5178207/arturo-menchaca) I changed my code like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DBContext, MigrateDBConfiguration<DBContext>>());

...
```

After the change this exception is occurring:

> There is already an object named 'MyTable' in the database.

How can I apply my database migration?

Comment: One thing to check is to see if you have changed your namespaces at all.  Entity Framework migrations are very sensitive to namespacing as that seems to be where a lot of the voodoo seems to happen with migrations.  I was burned in the past by a adjusting namespaces to fit the folder structure that migrations creates by default.

Comment: it sounds like you are combining automatic migrations with manual migations.  This can cause some serious migrationHistory issues in the database (at least as far as i have experienced).  If you are generating manual migrations try turning off automatic migrations.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution to my problem. I call this method in each application start :

```
public void InitializeDatabase(DataAccessManager context)
{
    if (!context.Database.Exists() || !context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false))
    {
        var configuration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration();
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
        migrator.Configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");
        var migrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();
        if (migrations.Any())
        {
            var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);
            var script = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(null, migrations.Last());

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(script))
            {
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot thanks! I improved on this slightly though by just using `migrator.Update();` instead of getting the script out and executing that directly

Comment: Daft question alert: which library is this DataAccessManager class in?

Answer (score 22):

*Automatic Migrations* means that you don't need to run `add-migration` command for your changes in the models, but you have to run `update-database` command manually.

If *Automatic Migrations* is enabled when you call `update-database`, if there are pending changes in your models, an 'automatic' migration will be added and database will be updated.

If you want that your database is updated without need to call `update-database` command, you can add `Database.SetInitializer(...)` in `OnModelCreating()` method on your context, like so:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, MigrateDBConfiguration>());
    }

    ...
}

public class MigrateDBConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    ...
```

Note that you should declare `DbMigrationsConfiguration` and `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` with your real context, not the default `DbContext`.

Comment: this is actually not true.  By using the MigrateToTheLatestMigrationVersion database intializer this should work (it has worked in the past for me).  I am actually having this same issue right now.  I am not sure what i changed but i know this setup has worked in the past.

Comment: I want that my database is updated without need to call update-database and try your solution and not work.

Comment: @Fred: In your code you have declared `MigrateDBConfiguration` as `DbMigrationsConfiguration<DbContext>`, `DbContext` is the name of you context?, if that is the case, be aware of not to confuse it with `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca my DbContext class name is DbAccess, in above question write DbContext to simplicity.

Comment: @Fred: And `Database.SetInitializer(...` is called in `OnModelCreating` or `DbAccess` constructor?

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca Database.SetInitializer(... called in OnModelCreating like last edit my question

Comment: seems like your applied migrations to database and _MigrationHistory table values are not synchronized, can you drop your tables including _MigrationHistory (if not at least delete MyTable) and try it again?

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca yes it work.but I want to apply my explicit generated migration in future and I can not delete MyTable per each migration

Comment: @Fred: This should not happens again, but note that drops operations cant be done with automatic migrations, but code-based migrations. If you add a set using automatic migration, then just remove it from the context and run the program, then add it back with an code-based migration this kind of error will happens, you should be aware when combine automatic with code-based migrations.

Answer (score 6):

If you have change in your entities, you need first run `add-migration` to create the migration script.

After that in your `Global.asax`

you need to have some code like this

```
        var configuration = new MyProject.Configuration();
        var migrator = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator(configuration);            

        migrator.Update();
```

every time that you run your asp.net project it'll check if you have a new migration to run and run `update-database` automatically for you.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft addresses migrations at runtime, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime).

For example, you can do this in `Program.cs`: (tested working in .NET 5.0 preview)

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    MigrateDatabase(host);

    host.Run();
}

private static void MigrateDatabase(IHost host)
{
    using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    try
    {
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred creating the DB.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the original question was related to entity-framework, not entity-framework-core.

Answer (score -1):

### using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

- 
- 

```
        await _dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
        _dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

OR

```
        await _dbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
         _dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

both method check if database exist, if not they both create it.

- Migrate() uses migrations and is suitable if you use migrations or relational database.
- EnsureCreated() does not use migrations which means once db is created using this method no further migrations can be executed over it.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62225872/861716) has a much better explanation of `Database.Migrate()`. It isn't working just like that as you suggest.

Comment: True this, I just posted another way :)